# Set-Cookie not set

Tags: .net, cookies, http-headers, setcookie

I have the following issue with the cookie, for the API I'm using ASP .Net WebAPI project, for UI Angular app, from the UI during the login process I'm sending POST request with FormData body and with withCredentials: true flag

[image]

On the API I have configured CORS, and the response for the login request looks following

[image]

The login request successfully passed, and in response I have set-cookie header with attributes: secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None. But this cookie not stored in browser storage, could you please help what could be the case?

The increasing of expiration date doesn't solve the problem

[image]

Comment: If no expiration date is set, a cookie becomes a session entry. Looking into the session storage, can you locate it there?

Comment: No the session and the cookie storage are empty

Comment: You should be good to go if you add the epxires information. Maybe Chrome is programmed in a way that it just ignores the cookie or only saves it in memory when no expiration date is given.

Comment: tried to add expiration date, but results remain the same
I've updated question with details

Comment: Does this also not function in e.g. firefox?